# Changing homebrew-cask installation directories

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I recently installed homebrew-cask and one of the things that I see is that it installs applications by default into the following directories:

1. Versioned package downloads => **/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/**

   Example : `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/pdftk/2.02`
2. Application binaries/libraries => **/opt/**

   Example : `/opt/pdftk/bin/`

Instead of using the **/opt** directory, I would really like to use a directory located in **/usr/local** which is where my homebrew installation resides.

I can see from the docs that I can set an environment variable for #1, but I can't seem to figure out where to change #2.

I'd like to have the above two settings go to:

1. `/usr/local/Caskroom/packages/pdftk/2.02`
2. `/usr/local/Caskroom/pdftk/bin`

Any ideas on how I can change both settings or are there good ideas why I wouldn't want to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the Caskroom manual (specifically the [Usage manual](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md)) you can change where the actual application will be installed by adding a line like this to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshenv` etc.

```
# Specify your defaults in this environment variable
export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--appdir=/Applications --caskroom=/usr/local/Caskroom"
```

Comment: I was having issues with `export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--appdir=/Applications --caskroom=/usr/local/Caskroom"`


An issue post on brew's github suggests to remove `--caskroom=/usr/local/Caskroom` from that command.  Works fine now.